# How to find all optimal DNF forms in discrete maths?

Tags: python, graph, discrete-mathematics

I tried to write the code in Python, but I can't quite get it how to print all the possible DNF forms with their truth tables. I wrote a code for that, but it doesn't print anything, where I made mistakes?

It would also be good if someone could share some ideas on how to display the graphs derived from the truth tables as Boolean algebra. In this code I tried to find all DNF of length 2 and size 3. Maybe somebody has some ideas how to deal with these things, I would be very grateful.

```
import itertools

def generate_dnf(variables, length=None, size=None):
    num_vars = len(variables)
    dnf_formulas = []

    if length is None:
        lengths = range(num_vars + 1)
    else:
        lengths = [length]

    if size is None:
        sizes = range(num_vars + 1)
    else:
        sizes = [size]

    for n in lengths:
        for combination in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=num_vars):
            if sum(combination) == n:
                dnf = ''
                for i in range(num_vars):
                    if not combination[i]:
                        dnf += '~'
                    dnf += variables[i]
                    dnf += ' or '
                dnf_formulas.append(dnf[:-4])

    filtered_dnf_formulas = []
    for formula in dnf_formulas:
        num_operators = formula.count(' or ') + formula.count(' and ')
        if num_operators in sizes:
            filtered_dnf_formulas.append(formula)

    return filtered_dnf_formulas

variables = ['A', 'B', 'C']
dnfs = generate_dnf(variables, length=2, size=3)
for dnf in dnfs:
    print(dnf)
```

Comment: One observation: you do `num_operators = formula.count(' or ') + formula.count(' and ')`, but the word 'and' is never part of the formulas you produce.

Comment: Can you share the output you are expecting? i.e. what are the formulas with length=2 and size=3 that you expect from variables ['A', 'B', 'C']?

Comment: For example: length=2, size=3, it would be (A) ∨ (C ∧ ¬B) (length 2 means that there is only two conjunctions, size means how many operators we have, in this case, we have 3 (A, B, C))

Comment: Thanks. So (1) it seems like your calculation of `num_operators` needs to include `~` as well as 'or' and 'and', (2) your current code never includes 'and' in the formulas it produces.

Comment: Okey, thank you. Maybe could you tell me how to include 'and'?

Comment: That seems more like a question about DNFs than a question about Python, and I'm not very familiar with DNFs, sorry.

Comment: Could you clarify, what length and size would `(A ∧ B) ∨ (C ∧ ¬B) ∨ (D ∧ B)` correspond to, for example?

Comment: Length is how many conjunctions in one equation we have (in your given equation, length is 3), size is how many literals we have (in your given equation, size is 4)